# Mutation working on GraphQL explorer, but not working when sent from nuxt frontend

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have this GraphQL:

```
mutation MyMutation($dayPhone: String!, $email: String!, $firstName: String!, $noOfDoors: String!, $noOfFrenchPatio: String!, $noOfWindows: String!, $postcode: String!, $quotationDate: DateTime!, $quotationId: String!, $refCode: String!, $surname: String!, $slug: String!, $authorId: ID!) {
  save_quotes_quotation_Entry(
    dayPhone: $dayPhone
    email: $email
    firstName: $firstName
    noOfDoors: $noOfDoors
    noOfFrenchPatio: $noOfFrenchPatio
    noOfWindows: $noOfWindows
    postcode: $postcode
    quotationDate: $quotationDate
    quotationId: $quotationId
    refCode: $refCode
    surname: $surname
    slug: $slug
    authorId: $authorId
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

When executed in my GraphQL explorer inside of Craft CMS it works perfectly, a quotation entry gets created, when executed from my nuxt3 frontend I get the following error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Cannot query field \"save_quotes_quotation_Entry\" on type \"Mutation\".",
            "extensions": {
                "category": "graphql"
            },
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 16,
                    "column": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Why would this be, both are using the exact same syntax.

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the same GraphQL server from nuxt3?